# How can I find some distance from my location with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, annotations, location

I have an app that takes some results(lat,long) from my server and put annotations in my map depends the lat and long that it took.

Now i put a slider that filters the results by kilometers (1-10)

How can i filter my query to add the annotation if the lat an long is in its radius location.

Comment: Check out the `distanceFromLocation()` method in the `CLLocation` class

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted but i think the reason is not providing a code sample. Stack Overflow should add a visible reason to downvoting so it is obvious what to improve to the question.

Comment: @Emptyless i deserve the downvote that's why i didn't say anything in comments but anbu.karthik didn't even if his answer was wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1**

Initially convert your lat and long to CLLocation.

**Step 2**

```
var one, two: CLLocation
// assign one and two
let distance = two.distanceFromLocation(one)
```

`CLLocationDistance` is just `double` and distance calculated in meters

**Step 3**

convert distance to meters

```
let distanceKM = distance / 1000
```

**step 4**

finally compare to distance with in range

```
if  distanceKM > 1000 &&  distanceKM < 10000
{
 // drop your pins 
}
```

Comment: i didn't downvote in fact now i'm trying to include your code to mine. (maybe the person who downvote me downvote you too)

Comment: ha ha ha does not a problem @mikevorisis . if he find the mistake is easy to   resolve some mistakes

Comment: @anbu-karthik I did downvote by mistake (I was on mobile, who knows what happened).

If you please edit the answer above (for example by changing the step titles from "step-X" to "step X"), I will change it to an upvote.

I'm sorry!

PS
It was my first time downvoting and I got so surprised when I opened stackoverflow and noticed that I now have earned the Critic badge (aka the badge that you get after downvoting for the first time).

Comment: Done! Thank you and, please, forgive me  have a nice day~

Comment: @FedericoZanetello - its ok bro